# Calling relative paths from test file: "Attempted Relative import beyond toplevel package"

Tags: python

I'm trying to perform unit testing from the given file structure

```
/logs_cleanup
---/cleanup_logs.py << target
/test
---/unit
------/python
---------/tests.py << test file
(Each directory has __init__.py)
```

Unit Testing command is

```
python -m unittest test.unit.python.tests
```

In tests.py file, I have this import statement:

```
from ....logs_cleanup.cleanup_logs import filename_matched
```

And it's causing this error below

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

The constraint is that,,, **I can't use sys.path.append call in the very first statement** because my pylint (Linting) doesn't allow it. is there any other solution?

Comment: It might make sense to use an absolute import. Just delete all the leading dots and it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

Having `__init__.py` on EVERY directory worked for me.

Then simply call:

`from logs_cleanup.cleanup_logs import filename_matched`

Done.